# Using vuejs via es6 modul in index.html without node

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, es6-modules

I am trying to add a vuejs frontend to my java backend (spring boot) without using node. I created a simple index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Hello Test!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>test test</h1>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

which is supposed to import the following main.js (located in the same folder) as module:

```
import Vue from './vue.js'

import {
  Navbar
} from './component/navbar.js'

import {
  MainTemplate
} from './templates/main-template.js'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    'navbar': Navbar
  },
  template: MainTemplate
})
```

When accessing localhost in either chrome or firefox, I get the header 'test test', but an error saying 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()' regarding the main.js.

I have found different tutorials stating that this should be working. Trying out different ways of importing the main.js didn't change the error.

As I really need to get this to work I would really appreciate any tips on that! Thanks in advance!

Comment: if main.js is indeed in the same folder as the index.html file, then it's your http server process that is somehow failing you - perhaps you need to expand the description of the server process

Comment: @JaromandaX could you explain how I could find out whether that is the problem? I'm only using the basic spring boot configurations for the webserver

Comment: in your browser address, replace index.html with main.js - do you get the main.js file?